# calling oracle stored procedure using custom data types in perl

Tags: oracle, perl, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure defined in oracle whose parameters are objects defined in oracle.

I need to invoke it through perl. I have looked but couldnt find any reference about it.

Could anyone help me out for the same ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write another Oracle procedure in which you can use your oracle-objects and call your target procedure? You could then call this new procedure by perl with standard parameters.

Bad architecture but should work...

(Sorry can't just comment)

Comment: Yes @evilive, I agree. I am looking at the ideal solution. Can I directly invoke it through perl is the issue.